# Datamaps: How to set conditional highlight fill colors for objects with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, topojson, datamaps

In the event that a country object has data in `location_data` I want one to set `highlightFillColor` to green, if not the object would either highlight in gray or disable the highlight altogether on hover. Here is what I'm currently using (to no effect): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7fn0644/3/)

```
highlightFillColor: function(data) {
  if (data) {
    return 'green';
  }
  return '#dbdbdb';
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already created a property named `fillKey` for those countries with data, you can simply do:

```
highlightFillColor: function(data) {
    if (data.fillKey) {
        return 'green';
    }
    return '#dbdbdb';
}
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvrsjj9f/